# OPOS, Windows 10 CCO

Tags: windows-10, opos

After installing "POSforDotNet-1.14" and "OPOS_CCOs_1.14.001" I can only use the pos devices with the local Administrator user. Logged in with another user, even if this user is added to the local administrators, OPOS throws an exception "The service object returned a failure status from its open call."

I think it's a permission issue, although a user in the local administrators should have the same permissions as the administrator user, shouldn't it?

I've tried lowering UAC to 0, but no improvement there.

My goal is to have this working for a standard (non administrator) user.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use OPOS 1.12.* instead 1.14.* or 1.13.*.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, it may be related not only to the UAC setting but also permission to rewrite the resources used by the OPOS service object.

For example, when opening a service object, the service object may rewrite the OPOS registry or delete and re-create the file in the C: \ Windows \ System32 folder.

Please contact your OPOS vendor if your OPOS service object is supported to work as a non-administrator user on Windows 10.